# Shopify Metafield late update after successful response by rest api

Tags: shopify-app, shopify-api

I'm updating product metafields in bulk in using shopify rest API, for different products and and every product have same namespace for the metafield.

```
foreach($products as $product){
   $metafield = [
      'namespace' => 'app_specific_metafield',
      'key' => 'variable_name'
      'value' => 'value'
   ]; 
}
```

and I update/create the metafield according to Shopify rest metafield API docs.
everything is fine, I get 200 for each product's metafield update.

**But when refresh the product's metafield, it didn't show the changes immediately, ( *after X number of time it appears* ). Idk if there is any time limit to get the updated metafields reflected.**

Answer (score 1):

Yes it takes Maximum 5 Minutes to reflects Metafields at front side

Comment: Do you have any reference for this?